# Error message 'Module qgis.v.kernel.rast.py not found'

Tags: qgis, heat-map

How do I repair this error in QGIS:

[image: Error message]

The error message was received whilst trying to run v.kernel from the modules list.  I can however run v.kernel from the GRASS shell.

A while ago, I installed a new plugin which apparently moved or deleted a whole lot of files.  The result was that I couldn't use NVIZ.  Uninstalling and re-installing QGIS didn't help so I finally resorted to manually locating the files and replacing them.  Not sure where to find this file however.  Is there anyone who can assist me how to repair this?

Answer (score 2):

This file comes with QGIS and you can find it as `src/plugins/grass/scripts/qgis.v.kernel.rast.py` (part of the internal grass plugin). While you could get it from the development repository, rather make sure you only have one copy of QGIS installed and that you are running the healthy one. If this is from some ancient version, renaming the configuration directory may also be needed.

Comment: Ok, really stupid question:  would you be referring to the source code available at:  http://fossies.org/dox/qgis-1.8.0/qgis_8v_8kernel_8rast_8py_source.html

Comment: Yes, that looks accurate.

Comment: How do I repair it?  I tried copying it over, but was denied access when I wanted to save it.

Comment: Get the required permissions if you want to do it that way. I don't know much about windows, but it would surely work if you switched to an "administrator" user.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give try running as 'administrator' and see if that helps.